# How should I do if I want to run a full node in GUI?

Tags: full-node

I'd like to run a full node within bitcoin-qt.exe(It's GUI)

I would like to run it as full node like typing command : "bitcoind -daemon"

Is it enough to run by just execute a GUI wallet(bitcoin-qt.exe)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Bitcoin Core is **always** a full node software and does not have any SPV components within it. Running any part of Bitcoin Core (bitcoind or bitcoin-qt) means that you are running a full node.

Comment: Thank you. and also I'd like to check whether other people can access to my node or not. Any idea for simply check it?

Comment: You just have to check the port 8333 is accessible from the internet. The easiest way to do that is to go to https://bitnodes.earn.com/ and go down to the bottom where it says "Join The Network". There your IP address should be entered (enter it if it is not or if it is wrong) and click the Check Node button.